# VLC stops the video before the end of the video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, vlc

VLC stops video before the end of video and prints this in terminal:

```
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c7f0c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c9da60] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318cff780] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c7f0c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c9da60] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318cff780] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c7f0c0] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d1b900] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318cff780] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d1b900] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c9da60] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] mmco: unref short failure
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 24718094: no reference clock
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 34926677: no reference clock
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Timestamp conversion failed for 45796649: no reference clock
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: Could not convert timestamp 0 for FFmpeg
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d1b900] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318c7f0c0] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318ce36c0] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318cff780] mmco: unref short failure
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d1b900] co located POCs unavailable
[h264 @ 0x7ff318d37b00] mmco: unref short failure
[00007ff318c6a260] main decoder error: buffer deadlock prevented
```

I created the video file converting the original video with this command:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -b 1000000 video_mod.mp4
```

The same file is played correctly using Firefox.

I converted other video files with that command and VLC can play them entirely.

How to solve this error?

Comment: The complete log from the `ffmpeg` command may be informative.

Comment: It may be using the wrong extension and firefox may be able to recognize it.